# Bash Alias with ternary?

Tags: bash, zsh, alias, conditional-operator, zsh-alias

Still dipping my toes in bash coding and trying to crate a 1 liner alias to:

- if 'perms' is entered w/out a parameter, it does a `stat -c '%a - %n' *`
- else if 'perms' is entered with a parameter it does `stat -c '%a - %n' <parameter>`
- Goal is if no param added, shows perms for all files/folders, else show perms for specified file/folder.

I've gotten this far with 2 different versions, but they both result in the same thing; WITH a parameter added it works fine; without a parameter it isn't getting the `*` added and the command says it requires a parameter. So for some reason the "if true" part is not filling the `$a` var, but the "else" part does fill it.

```
alias perms="a=$(if [ -z '$@' ]; then *; else $@; fi) stat -c '%a - %n' $a"

alias perms="a=$([[ -z '$1' ]] && '*' || $1) stat -c '%a - %n' $a"
```

Comment: Use  a function and enjoy.

Comment: Tag bash **or** zsh, not both at once. They're deeply incompatible shells, with design philosophies that force them apart further over time (bash tries to stay a superset of POSIX sh, zsh deliberately breaks the standard in places where it disagrees with standardized decisions).

Comment: (Also, `a && b || c` is not a ternary operator, and trying to use it as if it were one is liable to end in tears).

Comment: "Deeply incompatible" is an exaggeration; you make it sound like `fish`. `zsh` can (or can be configured to) run most `bash` code just as `bash` would. `zsh` makes no secret about its purpose as an enhanced *interactive* shell, not a replacement for executing shell scripts. If you really want it to be, you can configure `zsh` to be POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @chepner, sure -- when configured in POSIX mode it loses everything that makes it unique, though. I do stand behind my description of the failure to perform POSIX-mandated word-splitting an unquoted expansion as utterly fundamental; that operation is so ubiquitous that any nontrivial code written to take advantage of zsh's laxity will be buggy when run on POSIX-compliant shells. Certainly, one can write code that works for both -- you've done it with your answer -- but folks need to be mindful; "eh, works on zsh, so this should be fine for everyone" is Not Okay.

Comment: (I'm a lot happier with fish: it's _obviously_ not a POSIX shell, to a degree that makes it harder for finger memory / habits to inadvertently transfer)

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `bash` and `zsh`?

Comment: "liable to end in tears" lmao. Trust me, it did end in tears, lol. Dealing w/Linux when you've been a Windows guy your whole life usually does. Kinda glad I did tag both though; it's been an educational discussion for me. ;)

Comment: @EdMorton-SOstopbullying I thought that was a very odd "ternary" as well, using a `&&` and `||`, but came across it in searches, including here on SO, so gave it a shot. Bummer though that there are no ternary's in bash ... I tend to find ternarys ded sexeh. :p

Comment: @J.ScottElblein then you'll be very disappointer if you ever have to use [Go](https://go.dev/) (aka `Golang`) as the providers think the rest of us are too stupid to be trusted with ternaries:-). I agree with you FWIW - they're extremely useful when used sensibly.

Comment: I *have* been wanting to skinny dip in the Golang waters as well lately. Been debating on either Golang, Python, or JS. There are NO ternarys in Go?! *clutches invisible pearls*

Comment: Right, no ternaries in Go (google it for the providers' highly debatable rationale which really does boil down to "everyone's too stupid to use them properly").

Comment: Technically, `bash` *does* have a ternary operator.... if you are in an arithmetic context. `x=$(( y < 0 ? -1 : y > 0 ? 1 : 0))`, for example, works as a quasi-`sign` function.

Comment: Aside from what chepner mentioned: `$(x ....)` runs the command `x`, where `x` is an external command, or a function, or an alias.  `if` is neither of those, unless you happen to have an executable program named _if_ somewhere in your PATH. Same is true for `[[`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a function. (*Most* things people try to use aliases for should be functions.)

```
perms () {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    stat -c '%a -%n' *
  else
    stat -c '%a - %n' "$@"
  fi
}
```

Comment: I had to add `function` before `perms` or else error. After that, running great, thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of any shell that requires `function`.

Comment: It happened to me w/OMZ

Answer (score 2):

You should use a function. You could do something like this:

```
perms() { files=( * ); stat -c '%s - %n' "${@:-${files[@]}}"; }
```

which stores the contents of the current directory in  an array `files[]` and then prints `"$@"` if populated or `"${files[@]}"` otherwise. The problem with that is if there are no files in your directory than `*` would be passed to `stat` literally and fail complaining there's no file named `*` and exit with a failure status, both of which I assume would be undesirable behavior, e.g. running in an empty directory:

```
$ perms() { files=( * ); stat -c '%s - %n' "${@:-${files[@]}}"; }
$ perms
stat: cannot stat '*': No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

You could add `shopt -s nullglob` to try to solve that problem but then stat would fail complaining about a null argument:

```
$ perms() { shopt -s nullglob; files=( * ); stat -c '%s - %n' "${@:-${files[@]}}"; }
$ perms
stat: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

so that alone doesn't solve the problem (and you'd also need to set `nullglob` back to it's previous value before leaving the function so that wouldn't be enough of a change anyway).

So, I'd recommend you do this instead:

```
$ perms() {
    local files
    if (( $# > 0 )); then
        files=( "$@" )
    else
        local orig_nullglob=$(shopt -p nullglob)
        shopt -s nullglob
        files=( * )
        $orig_nullglob
    fi
    if (( "${#files[@]}" > 0 )); then
        stat -c '%s - %n' "${files[@]}"
    fi
}

$ > foo
$ > bar

$ perms foo
0 - foo

$ perms
0 - bar
0 - foo

$ rm foo bar

$ perms
$ echo $?
0
```

and that will only exit with a failure exit status if one of the commands in the function fails or you pass it an argument for a file name that doesn't exit, which I assume would be desirable behavior:

```
$ perms nonsense
stat: cannot stat 'nonsense': No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

The above assumes you're using `bash` as you tagged. If you're actually using `zsh` as you also tagged then idk what changes would be needed.